# Left Join With IS NULL

Tags: sql, node.js, sqlite, join, left-join

I have 2 tables Users(Name TEXT) and 'Coffee Breaks'(Person1 TEXT, Person2 TEXT).

I need to write a join that will return all the users a given user hasn't had a Coffee Break with.

I'm attempting to do a left join with IS NULL on the right side.

The db query is completing without error but I am not getting any users in the result. Is the issue with my SQL query string?

SQL:

```
WITH bilateral(p1, p2) AS (SELECT Person1 AS p1, Person2 AS p2 FROM "Coffee Breaks"
   UNION ALL SELECT Person2 AS p1, Person1 AS p2 FROM "Coffee Breaks"
   GROUP BY p1, p2)
SELECT * FROM Users u1, Users u2
   LEFT JOIN bilateral bi ON u1.Name=bi.p1 AND u2.Name=bi.p2
   WHERE bi.p1 IS NULL
```

Sample Data:

```
Users
[
  {
    Name: "Casey"
  },
  {
    Name: "Jake"
  },
  {
    Name: "Mark"
  },
  {
    Name: "Steve"
  }
]

Coffee Breaks
[
  {
    Person1: "Steve",
    Person2: "Casey"
  }
]
```

Server Code:

```
db.neverCoffeed = function(user) {
  const sql = `WITH bilateral(p1, p2) AS (SELECT Person1 AS p1, Person2 AS p2 FROM "Coffee Breaks"
    UNION ALL SELECT Person2 AS p1, Person1 AS p2 FROM "Coffee Breaks"
    GROUP BY p1, p2)
  SELECT * FROM Users u1, Users u2
    LEFT JOIN bilateral bi ON u1.Name=bi.p1 AND u2.Name=bi.p2
    WHERE bi.p1 IS NULL`;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.run(sql, (err, users) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      else {
        console.log('users', users)
        resolve(users);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: SQLite just treats comma as if it were spelled "cross join". In standard SQL comma ie "implicit join" means cross join but it binds more loosely than "explicit joins", those using JOIN keyword. So don't mix implicit with explicit joins. (If you do, put the comma joins last.) Here in another DBMS your code would mean first left joining then cross joining. Which would give an error since there's no u1. columns in the left join.

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. Justify "minimal code with a problem" for required functionality via a part of that code that works for a maximal part of that functionality. Show that your program calculates what you expect it to as it goes through (sub)expressions--including that arguments passed to each function/operator meet its requirements-- by saying what that is & showing that it actually does it via incremental output. Ask about the (small) difference between the examples. This is basic debugging. PS Your description of desired output as a function of output isn't very clear.

Comment: Do you understand that your group by applies to the 2nd argument of the union, not to the union? Symmetry suggests you don't want to just group one of the selects. Whichever you intend it's hard to know just what you are trying to do with it. Given your final left join left input, it doesn't matter whether there are duplicate user pairs in the right table, because you only keep rows without matches. But if you did want unique pairs after the union you could just union [distinct] instead of instead of group by of a union all.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect something like this:

```
select u.*
from users u
where not exists (select 1
                  from coffeebreaks cb
                  where (cb.person1 = u.name and cb.person2 = ?) or
                        (cb.person2 = u.name and cb.person1 = ?)
                 );
```

The `?` is a placeholder for the person of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this part

```
SELECT * FROM Users u1, Users u2
    LEFT JOIN bilateral bi ON u1.Name=bi.p1 AND u2.Name=bi.p2
    WHERE bi.p1 IS NULL
```

To

```
(SELECT * FROM Users u1
    LEFT JOIN bilateral bi ON u1.Name=bi.p1
    WHERE bi.p1 IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Users u2
    LEFT JOIN bilateral bi ON u2.Name=bi.p2
    WHERE bi.p2 IS NULL)
```